# 'promise' return empty array

Tags: node.js, promise

I am trying to return Array of tokens stored in Firebase, and I am using 'promise'.

```
function getUsersTokens() {
 let dbRef = db.ref('/system/users');
 let result = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    dbRef.once('value', (snap) => {
        let tokens = [];
        snap.forEach(child => {
            if(child.Status != "occupied"){
                helper.getToken(child.key,db).then(function(token){
                    tokens.push(token);
                });
            }       
        }); 
        resolve(tokens);
    }, (err) => {
        reject(err);
    });
 });
 return result;
  }
```

and this is the 'getToken' method from the "helper" module.

```
exports.getToken=function(uid,db){
   return db.ref(`/Tokens/${uid}`).once('value').then(function(result){
     return result.val();
   });
};
```

The problem is that every time I push token into the array it all works fine, but when exit getUsersTokens() the array gets empty.

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your `result` promise is resolving too early because the `helper.getToken()` is non-blocking, so your `forEach` will finish running before all of the `getToken()` calls have finished pushing their token into `tokens`.

To make things a little easier, you can split your `result` promise into two promises. The first promise will be in charge of getting `snap`. The second promise will be in charge of iterating through `snap` to produce an array of tokens:

```
function getUsersTokens() {

    let dbRef = db.ref('/system/users');

    let result = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        dbRef.once('value', (snap) => {
            resolve(snap);
        }, (err) => {
            reject(err);
        });
    });

    return result.then(snap => {

        let prommiseArr = [];

        snap.forEach(child => {
            if(child.Status != "occupied"){
                let p = helper.getToken(child.key,db);
                promiseArr.push(p);
            }  
        });

        return Promise.all(promiseArr); // resolves to array of tokens

    });
}
```

`Promise.all` takes in an array of promises, and resolves when all of those promises have also resolved. the promise returned by `getUsersToken` will ultimately contain an array of tokens, because each promise of `promiseArr` resolves to a token.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because the promise is resolved with the token array before `getToken()` resolves itself. You see an empty array because your handler runs before the tokens arrive.

You need to wait on that before resolving. Like this:

```js
function getUsersTokens() {
  let dbRef = db.ref('/system/users');
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    dbRef.once('value', (snap) => {
      const tokensPromise = snap
        .filter(child => child.Status !== "occupied")
        .map(child => helper.getToken(child.key, db));
      resolve(Promise.all(tokensPromise));
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Promise.all as pointed out by @André Werlang and @Christian Santos it perfect here is an example using reduce way

```
function getUsersTokens() {
 let dbRef = db.ref('/system/users');
 let result = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    dbRef.once('value', (snap) => {
       snap.reduce((chain, child) => {
          return chain.then(array => {
             return helper.getToken(child.key,db).then(function(token){
                return array.push(token);
              });
          });
       }, Promise.resolve([])).then(tokens=>{
                    resolve(tokens);
                });
    }, (err) => {
        reject(err);
    });
 });
 return result;
  }
```

Comment: it wouldn't work because tokens are pushed onto the array at a later time. also `Promise.resolve([])` is tricky and relies on the fact that resolving a promise isn't immediate.